# Move common legend to top right of plots in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

in my code below, I wanted some help to move my common legend to the top right of the plots like this:

[image]

Can you assist me with this?  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  Iter  abs11  abs21  abs12  abs22
     1, 0.0016930, 0.0007109, 0.0169301, 0.0071087
     2, 0.0004656, 0.0006430, 0.0046563, 0.0064301
     3, 0.0001496, 0.0010624, 0.0014964, 0.0106239
     4, 0.0000946, 0.0006596, 0.0009458, 0.0065962
     5, 0.0000274, 0.0002370, 0.0002737, 0.0023697
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
  group size= 1  by 2,
  vertical sep=2cm,
  horizontal sep = 2cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,group name=ape},
  width=15cm,
  height=8cm,
  try min ticks=5,
  scaled ticks=false,
  ]
\nextgroupplot[align =center,ymin=0, ymax=0.02,
title={\textbf{\emph{(a) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.001^{2})}$}}},
grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x    index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks]    {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}
\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=0.02,
title = {\textbf{\emph{(b) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.01^{2})}$}}},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
  node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large{\bf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}}
  (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
  coordinate(legendpos)
  (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
\ref{plots:plot1}& $\delta r_{2}$ &[5pt]
\ref{plots:plot2}& $\delta r_{3}$ &[5pt]\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Plot showing Absolute Errors with noise with parameters for RLSE.]{Plot showing RLSE Absolute Errors with noise with parameters (a) $N(0,0.001^{2})$ and (b) $N(0,0.001^{2})$.}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place it at `ape r1c1.north east`, with `anchor=south east`.

Note that `\large` is not a command that takes an argument, it is a switch and so should be used as `{\large text}` rather than `\large{text}`. And `\bf` is deprecated, as mentioned in a previous question.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  Iter  abs11  abs21  abs12  abs22
     1, 0.0016930, 0.0007109, 0.0169301, 0.0071087
     2, 0.0004656, 0.0006430, 0.0046563, 0.0064301
     3, 0.0001496, 0.0010624, 0.0014964, 0.0106239
     4, 0.0000946, 0.0006596, 0.0009458, 0.0065962
     5, 0.0000274, 0.0002370, 0.0002737, 0.0023697
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
  group size= 1  by 2,
  vertical sep=2cm,
  horizontal sep = 2cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,group name=ape},
  width=15cm,
  height=8cm,
  try min ticks=5,
  scaled ticks=false,
  ]
\nextgroupplot[align =center,ymin=0, ymax=0.02,
title={\textbf{\emph{(a) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.001^{2})}$}}},
grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}
]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x    index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks]    {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=0.02,
title = {\textbf{\emph{(b) RSLE Absolute Errors with $\mathbf{N(0,0.01^{2})}$}}},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};
\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\path (ape c1r1.north west-|current bounding box.west)--
  node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large\textbf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}
  (ape c1r2.south east-|current bounding box.west);
% legend

\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south east,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
  ] at(ape c1r1.north east)
  {
\ref{plots:plot1}& $\delta r_{2}$ &[5pt]
\ref{plots:plot2}& $\delta r_{3}$ &[5pt]\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Plot showing Absolute Errors with noise with parameters for RLSE.]{Plot showing RLSE Absolute Errors with noise with parameters (a) $N(0,0.001^{2})$ and (b) $N(0,0.001^{2})$.}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```